# Newly built INFO doesn't work

Tags: emacs, pdp-10, teco, incompatible-timesharing-system

I have ran into a problem involving ITS TECO, which I have a hard time getting past.

The problem is dumping a new standalone INFO.

In ITS, there is a file INFO; INFO EMACS which would seem to do this. `INFO$^S :EMACS` runs that file and dumps a new EMACS; TSINFO >.

However, that dumped INFO doesn't work fully. It starts EMACS, but doesn't enter INFO mode automatically. The problem seems to be that the INFO EMACS installs a macro calling `M(M.M Info Enter$)` in `FS ^R ENTER`, but that macro isn't run in the new INFO.

When I examine the value in `FS ^R ENTER` in the dumped INFO, it still has the default value, not the macro from INFO EMACS. So it seems dumping the new INFO doesn't save `FS ^R ENTER`, or running INFO doesn't pick up the new `FS ^R ENTER`.

How is INFO supposed to install a macro in `FS ^R ENTER` that persists in a dumped binary?

Comment: Sorry to post a useless comment, but I just want to say that I *love* the fact that there's an `[emacs]` question on Stack Overflow about the ITS TECO version :)

Comment: I don't have high hopes for an answer, but I did want an excuse to make the teco and pdp-10 tags. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by grabbing the text from INFO; INFO EMACS out of the TS INFO binary.  It was different from the corresponding source file.  Updating the source file with the new text fixed the problem.